Why is my tkinter Frame expanding when expand is set to False
I want to make a frame containing a left and right button and a frame that stores some products that can be clicked on. Yet, when I add the products into the frame with expand=False, it doesn't work.


code
root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry('1440x810')
root._set_scaling(1,1)
root.resizable(False, False)

left_img = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open('assets/promotion_left.png'), size = (20,40))
right_img = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open('assets/promotion_right.png'), size = (20,40))

category_row_3 = ctk.CTkFrame(root, fg_color = 'white', corner_radius = 0, border_width = 0)
category_row_3.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x', expand = True, padx = 15)

category_9_info = ctk.CTkFrame(category_row_3, fg_color = 'transparent', corner_radius = 0, border_width = 0)
category_9_info.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x')

category_9 = ctk.CTkFrame(category_row_3, fg_color = 'transparent', corner_radius = 0, border_width = 0)
category_9.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'both', expand = True)

category_9_left_button = ctk.CTkButton(category_9, text = '', image = left_img, fg_color = 'transparent', hover_color = '#f2f2f2')
category_9_left_button.pack(side = 'left', fill = 'y', ipadx = 5)

category_9_product_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(category_9, fg_color = 'transparent', corner_radius = 0, border_width = 0, width = 100)
category_9_product_frame.pack(side = 'left')

category_9_products = [1,2,3,4]
test = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open('assets/search_icon.png'), size = (200,200))
for product in category_9_products:
    ctk.CTkButton(category_9_product_frame, text = '', image = test).pack(side = 'left')

category_9_right_button = ctk.CTkButton(category_9, text = '', image = right_img, fg_color = 'transparent', hover_color = '#f2f2f2')
category_9_right_button.pack(side = 'right', fill = 'y', ipadx = 5)


If you set to False. The Frame will be on the top. I am usng Python 3.12.5 and Windows 10

see the answer of this question
